# What is the best solution for HTTP PUSH?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, comet, server-push

I started researching on Websockets and Comet... I found different ways to setup a server for HTTP PUSH.

The first is to use NGiNX with Node.js. Here is a tutorial on how to do it:

http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/04/nginx-php-fpm-and-node-js-install-on-centos-5-5/
and
http://blog.mixu.net/2011/08/13/nginx-websockets-ssl-and-socket-io-deployment/

Or

I can use a NGiNX module:

https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module

What is the best solution?

I am still a bit confuse about the different technologies.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Server Sent Events: https://github.com/chovy/nodejs-stream

Comment: The best solution depends on what technologies you're building on. i.e. it'll boil down to a language. What does your webserver stack look like? Are you using .NET, Java, Perl? Maybe include these in your question. Are you prepared to run new daemons/services to facilitate http push?